# Servicios Android

Tags: android, webservice, servicio

Desde mi Actividad (ActivityMain) puedo llamar a la CLASE `new WebService_modificar(MainActivity.this).execute();`La clase WebService_modificar tiene implementada las conexiones a la BBDD y mediante un fichero .PHP actualiza la fecha/hora capturada en mi EditText guardándola en mi bbdd remota (tengo que señalar que ejecutando la CLASE WebService_modificar desde el Main va perfecto). Pero ahora quiero que las actualizaciones de fecha/hora las realice en segundo plano la CLASE Servicio.

Tengo el servicio creado, pero no se como ejecutar la clase Webservice_modificar desde el servicio, ya que haciéndolo desde onStartCommand igual que en el Main me da error, ya que no me permite poner como contexto 'MainActivity.this', ni this, ni getAplicationContext. ¿Como puedo ejecutar el código de esta clase desde un servicio?

Aquí el código del servicio:

```
public class LocationUpdatesService extends Service {


/***************************************/


public LocationUpdatesService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }
    };

    createLocationRequest();
    getLastLocation();

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
    handlerThread.start();
    mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);

        NotificationChannel mChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, false);

    if (startedFromNotification) {
        removeLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mChangingConfiguration = true;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "in onBind()");
    stopForeground(true);
    mChangingConfiguration = false;
    return mBinder;
}
```

Este es el código del WebService_modificar:

```
class WebService_modificar extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

private Activity context;

WebService_modificar (Activity context){
    this.context=context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() { }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String resultado ="ERROR";

    if(modificar())
        resultado = "OK";
    else           
        resultado = "ERROR";

    return resultado;
}

protected void onPostExecute (String result) {

         if (result.equals("OK")) {         
        tostada("Datos modificados con éxito");
    }
    else
        tostada("ERROR, no se han modificado los datos");
} 

public void tostada (String mensaje) {
    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast1.show();
}

private boolean modificar(){
    boolean resul = false;

    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> parametros_POST;
    HttpPost httppost;
    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost= new HttpPost(URL_PHP+"update_apolo.php"); 

    //*********************************************************************************

    parametros_POST.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fecha", et_fechahora.getText().toString().trim()));


    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros_POST));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        resul = true;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        resul = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        resul = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {          
        resul = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resul;
}
```

Desde el Activity_Main ejecuto la clase Webservice_Mostrar con:

```
new WebService_modificar(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

¿Como puedo ejecutar esta clase desde el servicio?

Aquí es donde llamo a ejecutar la clase WebService_modificar

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
            false);

    if (startedFromNotification) {
        removeLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    //Aquí hay que meter el webService actualizar
    new WebService_modificar(mContext).execute();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: si quieres realizar en segundo plano tienes que usar un asynctask o handler que son metodos para crear hilos secundarios.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler ya puedes usar la que mas te convenga, la diferencia fundamental es que Asyntask es para tareas menos pesadas mas sencillas, en tu casa creo que seria mejor
Un saludo espero que te sirva.

Comment: La clase WebService_modificar ya hereda de AsyncTask. El problema que encuentro es que sí puedo ejecutar esta clase desde el main tal cual describo arriba, pero no desde la clase del servicio. No me permite poner this o getAplicationContext, en lugar de MainActivity.this. Y no encuentro forma de que el servicio ejecute esta clase.

Comment: pon el codigo para verlo mejor

Comment: @Chiscu explica mejor cómo tienes organizado el código editando la pregunta. Por ejemplo si son dos `Activity` puedes pasar datos entre ellas a través de `Intent`. Si una es `Activity` y la otra es sólo una clase que usas para conectar al WS habría que ver la forma más idónea para conectar la `Activity` y esa clase que gestiona el WS.

Comment: entiendo que tendras que llamar desde el main a la clases WebService_modificar y desde esa clase a la otra, si quieres mandme el proyecto y te lo miro, porque con eso solo no veo los errores que te da.

Comment: Hola Jesús, perdona la tardanza. Aquí tienes el proyecto, a ver si me puedes echar una mano y ves como puedo ejecutar las actualizaciones en segundo plano.  https://github.com/Chiscu/kakao

Comment: por fa, añade en tu pregunta en la clase LocationUpdatesService donde estas llamando a WebService_modificar

Answer (score 0):

Un servicio es ya en si un Contexto así que podrías en `onStartCommand()` hacer algo como:

```
Context mContext = this;
//o también 
Context mContext = nombreDetuClase.this;  
//luego llama a tu clase y pasale el contexto:
new WebService_modificar(mContext).execute();
```

Suerte ya me cuentas.. :)

Comment: Ahora me da error y me muestra varias soluciones :castear el contexto a Activity, crear constructor con contexto en WebServices_modificar, o crear constructor. Creando un nuevo constructor se ejecuta la app pero no modifica la BBDD.

Comment: private Activity context;

Comment: debe ser private Context context

Comment: estabas intentando pasar una actividad como contexto

Comment: La app funciona pero, el WebService no modifica los datos a diferencia de si lo ejecuto en el Main.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la depuración he conseguido dar con el error. El motivo del mismo era que quería modificar los valores de los campos de la bbdd con los valores obtenidos de los EditText, y claro cuando ejecutaba la clase WebService_modificar desde el Main (primer plano), los datos cambiaban, y los cogía para modificarlos en la bbdd sin problema. **Al estar el ActivityMain en segundo plano no puedo coger los valores de esos campos sino directamente de los métodos por los cuales obtengo la fecha y demás datos.**

De igual manera gracias a todos por vuestros comentarios, porque me han servido para poder indagar y estar más encima del código.